# Java Quartz tutorial not working

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Forgive me for being a Java newbie-- I was experimenting with Quartz but am having difficulty getting the basic tutorial to run:

```
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
public class QuartzTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            // and start it off
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Appears to compile fine, but when running, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: verification failed at PC 1134 in org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory:instantiate(()Lorg.quartz.Scheduler;): String, int, or float constant expected
   at _Jv_BytecodeVerifier.verify_fail(byte, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_BytecodeVerifier.verify_instructions_0() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_VerifyMethod(_Jv_InterpMethod) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_PrepareClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_WaitForState(java.lang.Class, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.linkClass0(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.resolveClass(java.lang.Class) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_ResolvePoolEntry(java.lang.Class, int) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at QuartzTest.main(java.lang.String[]) (Unknown Source)
```

I don't believe the quartz.properties file is an issue (doc seems to indicate that it's not needed for something this basic), but I've got it available anyway, with the basic options:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

jars on the classpath include:

```
libgcj-4.1.0.jar
quartz-2.2.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a requirement that you cannot use oracle jdk instead of GNU java?

Comment: Try this link it works fine, http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/

Comment: No, I went with what was installed on the system rather than downloading a separate JDK.  Do you think it would be solved with a different version?

Comment: Not everything works in GCJ, Try `OpenJDK` or Oracle Java

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, Oracle JDK 1.7 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide job class and trigger to run. This may help. http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example1

Comment: I'm not sure I follow-- at this point, I'm just attempting to start up the scheduler, I'm not even running anything. Just start and stop. See here:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start

Do I need to actually give it a trigger & job? IE, won't run when empty? (The guide seems to imply that this should be fine?)

Comment: You need to fire some job which will be task you want to run using scheduler right ?

Comment: he does not need a `Job` and `Trigger` to start the scheduler.